# React wait for data from custom hook before moving to next hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am working with both React Firebase. I am trying to figure out fetching and passing data around. In a functional component I am using a custom hook to get the loged in used:

```
const { user } = userAuthContext()
const profile = useDocument(“members”, user.uid)

Return (
    <div>
        <p>{profile.name}</p>
    </div>
)
```

The problem I run into is that ‘user’ is *undefined* when passed to useDocument()
Therefore, I can’t get the profile.

I am trying to figure how to wait until user gets a value, then proceed with the code, passing the value of user to the useDocument() hook to get the profile.

I was hopping someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot wait for hooks, they are meant to be asynchronous and to send a new value / to be executed everytime it is needed.

So the solution would be to check the value of `uid` passed in `useDocument`, and to return undefined if `uid` is not set.

```
const profile = useDocument(“members”, user?.uid)
```

```
const useDocument(type, uid) {
  if(!uid) return undefined
  // etc...
}
```

If profile is undefined, you will have to be careful during the render, because something like this :

```
   <div>
        <p>{profile.name}</p>
    </div>
```

Will trigger an error. So you will have check if profile is set with the optional chaining operator (like this: `profile?.name`) or make a conditional rendering according to the value of profile

```
if(!profile) return null // Or a loader can be better
return (
     <div>
        <p>{profile.name}</p>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for shading light on this. This suggestion above helps prevent and avoid errors. but I am not sure how it helps in attempting to get a value for profile and successfully rendering the name of the profile. Will useDocument() reevaluate when user gets a value ?

Comment: Yes, but it will only work if the hook `useDocument` is correctly implemented, meaning that it use a self state that is updated according to the passed parameters. For example with a useEffect triggered every time the parameter uid changes, and a state for the current value of the profile (that is the value returned by the hook)